# Definition of multi resolution analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

[image]

How can (a) $V_j \subseteq V_{j+1}$ be true, yet (c) is also true? Does that mean that $V_j$ as $j \rightarrow -\infty = \{0\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) and c) are quite compatible. Remember that the intersection is over **all** integers. If we have an orthonormal set $(x_n)$ indexed by all integers and $V_j$ is the closed subspace spanned by $\{x_n: n \leq j\}$ then b) and c) are both true.

Yes, c) means that $V_j$ decreases to $\{0\}$ as $j$ decreases to $ -\infty$.